# facing problem in conversion of binary string into byte array

Tags: android, android-studio, native

**I want to convert binary `string into` `byte` array, I'm using the above code for conversion but its showing the exception which is like above exception.please anyone help me to get the solution for this.**

**Code :**

```
byte[] bval = new BigInteger(passenger_sign, Character.MAX_RADIX).toByteArray();
```

**problem:**

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:
```

Comment: brother this time i change the correct data and its a binary data.....and it came in a correct format.

Comment: @mohamedfazurullah have u read the error `NumberFormatException: For input string: "["` Your input data is **`WRONG  `**

Comment: my data is correct but it cant change to byte array from binary.

Comment: in my back office it store in a binary format i can get this binary format as a string in json format.

Comment: pls clarify one thing how to convert binary string to byte array....if i get this 

i can get the solution...

Comment: i cant get ur question clearly...actually that image store in a binary format in db.
pls clarify how to get that image(in a binary format) from db and set it in app side...

Comment: passenger_sign length is: 90772--->this is length for that string

Comment: okay, suppose if ur image is in binary format, how do you get the binary image from db and show it in ur app side...

Comment: this what i want...

Answer (score 0):

the wrong is obvious,which appear in your "passenger_sign".it's has the wrong char '['.

look at the source.
[image: First Method][image: SecondMethod]

> but i can't know what's it in your "passenger_sign",so i can't sure which line code show the error.for more information,you should supply your "passenger_sign".

Comment: binary string is passing in the passenger sign

Comment: @mohamedfazurullah i need what's the strings in your variable " passenger_sign"
or you can check your result above the image code.

Comment: -119,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,2,-128,0,0,1,44,8,6,0,0,0,83,-5----> it having this string....